# Полный код встроенной функции sort в js

Tags: javascript

Где можно найти полный код встроенной функции sort в js?
 Вот например код map из книги "Выразительный JavaScript":

```js
function map(array, transform) {
var mapped = [];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
mapped.push(transform(array[i]));
return mapped;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6640347/javascript-native-sort-method-code?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нативные методы реализованы не на js, а в зависимости от движка, скорей всего это будет С.

Comment: Значит, методы forEach, map, и.т.д. не нативные для js? Если нет, то где почитать об этом?

Comment: да всё верно. это нативные методы. которых нет в es5, который в основном используется для браузеров, а есть в следующем стандарте es6+, который поддерживает тот же node.js, react и тд. (старые браузеры поддерживают частично или вовсе не поддерживают). Ваш пример это полифил который может использоваться как замена map там где он не поддерживается. неплохой ресурс https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/ или можно почитать сам стандарт http://ecma-international.org/

Comment: Спасибо большое